# Plotting Time Series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working on 16 world indices over three year and i want to make a plot from these 16 indices.

```
all<-read.table("C.../16indices.txt")
dimnames(all)[[2]]<-c("Date","BEL 20","CAC 40","AEX","DAX","FTSE 100","IBEXx 35","ATX","SMI","FTSE MIB","RTX","HSI","NIKKEI 225","S&P 500","NASDAQ","Dow Jones","BOVESPA")
attach(all)
```

Problems

1. My dates are written in the form "2009-01-05". I want only "2009" to appear otherwise i would have to many jumps.
2. For example the prices from the BOVESPA go from 40.000,15 to 60.000,137. How do I get nice y-labels? For instance 40.000, 45.000,...,60.000.
3. How do i get 16 of these plots in one nice figure/plot?

I'm not used to work with R. I tried something like this but that didn't work...

```
plot(all[1,],all[,2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biggest problem is no sample data> Here is advice based on guesswork:

```
 I tried something like this but that didn't work...   plot(all[1,],all[,2])
```

You need to format your date values as R Date class. If they are in YYYY-MM-DD format it will be as simple as:

```
 all$Date <- as.Date(all.Date)
```

To your specific questions:

```
 1) My dates are written in the form "2009-01-05". I want only "2009" to appear otherwise i would have to many jumps.
```

You will need to suppress axis plotting in the plot call and then need to add an axis() call.

```
 2) For example the prices from the BOVESPA go from 40.000,15 to 60.000,137. How do I get nice y-labels? For instance 40.000, 45.000,...,60.000.
```

You appear to be in a European locale and that mean your initial read.table call probably mangled the data input and you need to read the documentation for `read.csv2` which will properly handle the reversal of the decimal point and comma meanings for numeric data. You should also use colClasses.

```
 3) How do i get 16 of these plots in one nice figure/plot?
```

You should probably calculate ratios from an initial starting point for each series so there can be a common scale for display.